# Getting google static map at inbetween zoom levels that google maps site does?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I'm not sure if this is new in the Google maps site but you can use the scroll bar to zoom in-between the standard zoom levels.  The plus and minus buttons still jump a full zoom level and there doesn't appear to be any change in the raster in the in-between zoom levels although some road labels change (are they vector then?)

Can I get a static map at the in between zoom level as I often want it a bit more zoomed in but not all the way to the next level?

Also is the in-between zoom available in the JavaScript API?

It doesn't look like this is possible from the Google documentation but that's not always very up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible. Google request for this Issue in
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9948