# Google Maps is rounding my zoom level?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, google-maps-api

I am developing a python addin that allows the user to click on a location in arcmap and a browser window opens with the associated area in google maps.

The issue I am currently facing is that the formula I use creates a discrete zoom level resulting in zoom levels with 10 decimals, such as 17.7875321547z or 18.9062909847z.

The Formula I am using:

`level = (36.906 * scale**-0.088)
 url = "https://www.google.com/maps/@{0},{1},{2}z".format(y_coord, x_coord, level)`

My issue is that the url shows my provided zoom level but then rounds it down to the nearest whole number. From 17.7875321547z to 17 and so on.

I have found a similar question ([Can I get a google static map at the inbetween zoom levels that google maps site does?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223540)) that was asked almost 3 years ago with the only answer being that google had not fixed the issue at that point.

Has there been any progress since then?

Is there a way to use the specified zoom level without google rounding it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  These are your [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/options-when-question-is-duplicate-of-one-with-no-inadequate-old-answers).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation